# Strings fetched with JSON-API to be converted from base64 to UTF8 in Swift

Tags: json, swift, utf-8, character-encoding, base64

I am developing an iOS App that fetches Trivia Questions from [Open Trivia Database (API)](https://opentdb.com/api_config.php)
After reading the docs and played around with it I think that the best solution is to use base64 encoding (since it seems to be supported in Swift). I have successfully fetched the data and parsed it into structs using a JSONParser. The problem that I have to solve is how to convert the values from base64 to UTF8. (The keys are read correctly, and therefore it maps to my structs)

My first idea was to use `decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64`, but that does not seem to have any effect at all. And I am not really sure why.

Is that the right way to do it, or should I decode it myself afterwards when the strings are read in to structs? 
In short, the result of the Parsing is a struct containing a responseCode as an Int and array containing structs representing the questions with the strings that I want to convert to UTF8 as members

My code for parsing looks like this:

```
  let urlPath = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&encode=base64"
    let apiURL = URL(string: urlPath)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
            let questionData = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(questionData)
        }catch let err{
            print("Error", err)
        }
        }.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encoding is used for properties you declared as Data, not as Strings, like so:

```
struct Response: Codable {

   let someBaseEncodedString: Data


   var someString: String? {
      get {
         return String(data: someBaseEncodedString, encoding: .utf8)
      }
   }
}
```

So, for the example you are giving, all the properties that are returned as a base64 encoded string should have the Data type in your struct, and then after that decoded as strings.

Comment: This helped me out very much and I did not have to change a lot of my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other answers, you can decode `Data` or Base-64 `String` after `JSONSerialization` or `JSONDecoder` decoded the API results.

But if you prefer to write decoding initializer, you can make it as follows:

This may not be much different from your own `Response`, I guess.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var responseCode: Int
    var results: [Result]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseCode = "response_code"
        case results
    }
}
```

To prepare to write a decoding initializer for `Response`, I would like to use some extensions:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decodeBase64(forKey key: Key, encoding: String.Encoding) throws -> String {
        guard let string = try self.decode(String.self, forKey: key).decodeBase64(encoding: encoding) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: key, in: self,
                                                   debugDescription: "Not a valid Base-64 representing UTF-8")
        }
        return string
    }

    func decodeBase64(forKey key: Key, encoding: String.Encoding) throws -> [String] {
        var arrContainer = try self.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
        var strings: [String] = []
        while !arrContainer.isAtEnd {
            guard let string = try arrContainer.decode(String.self).decodeBase64(encoding: encoding) else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: key, in: self,
                                                       debugDescription: "Not a valid Base-64 representing UTF-8")
            }
            strings.append(string)
        }
        return strings
    }
}
```

Using these extensions above, you can define the `Result` type as follows:

```
extension Response {
    struct Result: Codable {
        var category: String
        var type: String
        var difficulty: String
        var question: String
        var correctAnswer: String
        var incorrectAnswers: [String]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case category
            case type
            case difficulty
            case question
            case correctAnswer = "correct_answer"
            case incorrectAnswers = "incorrect_answers"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.category = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .category, encoding: .utf8)
            self.type = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .type, encoding: .utf8)
            self.difficulty = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .difficulty, encoding: .utf8)
            self.question = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .question, encoding: .utf8)
            self.correctAnswer = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .correctAnswer, encoding: .utf8)
            self.incorrectAnswers = try container.decodeBase64(forKey: .incorrectAnswers, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }
}
```

(You have not mentioned if your `Response` (or other name?) is defined as a nested type or not, but I think you can rename or modify it yourself.)

With all things above, you can simply decode the API response as:

```
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let questionData = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(questionData)
        } catch {
            print("Error", error)
        }
```

---

By the way, you say ***I think that the best solution is to use base64 encoding (since it seems to be supported in Swift)***, but is that really true?

Base-64 to `Data` is supported in `JSONDecoder`, but it is not what you expect. So, using another encoding can be a better choice.

But, anyway, JSON string can represent all unicode characters using only ASCII with `\uXXXX` or `\uHHHH\uLLLL`. So, I do not understand why the API designers do not provide an option **Standard JSON Encoding**. If you can contact to them, please tell them to provide the option, that may simplify many client side codes.